# Is there a way to call a function expecting a pointer without creating variable?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have this function call:

```
uint32_t func(uint32_t* a, uint32_t b)
```

I want to call it with an integer literal like this:

```
func(0, b);
```

where `b` is a `uint32_t`.

Is there any way I can do this without creating an intermediate variable?
I.e. I want to avoid doing this:

```
uint32_t a = 0;
func(a, b);
```

Comment: You should use `func(&a, &b)`.

Comment: You can just call `func( nullptr, 43 )`.

Comment: `func(nullptr, 0);`  Am I missing something?

Comment: What would happen if you try this `func (&(0), 0)`? Would that be treated as reference to memory where first `0` is stored?

Comment: func (&(0), 0) throws an error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand. I believe it's because 0 is a temporary that does not necessarily reside in memory and therefore has no address that could be taken.

Comment: Do you have to do it often, in your code? I see a way to do it using a helper class that gets constructed as a temporary, and which provides an `operator int *();` You'll have to declare something like: `struct int_ptr {
 int v;

 operator int *() { return &v; }
};`, and then pass it like `func(int_ptr{0});`. This does have the overhead of declaring a helper class, up front. Not quite sure if this breaks any rules, yet, else I'd post it as an answer.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I am sorry, I am not familiar with coding in this manner. How would int_ptr{0} be converted to a pointer? Wouldn't this just create a struct?

Comment: Yeah, but you're passing it as an `int *` parameter, and, what a coincidence, the class provides an `operator int *()`, that just happens to return a pointer to an `int` value which was initialized with 0!

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, That's the right answer. This whole thing is a code smell, but if two lines per call is really too much of a problem, then your helper really is the best you'll get without changing the function itself. As for naming, I'd make it clear what the implications are with something like `func(temp_ptr_from_value(0));`. Preventing copying and moving might also be reasonable.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik This does seem to be the best answer. It works perfectly and does not use any other overhead. You can write an answer and I'll accept it. Could you also expand on what chris means by implications with naming?
Thanks!

Comment: In addition, the conversion operator should probably be marked as `&&` to prevent use on lvalues as a gesture of good will in case the warning in the name wasn't enough.

Comment: @pleasehalp, This helper is producing a pointer that will become dangling as soon as the object is destroyed. Using it like `int* p = int_ptr{0};` would cause `p` to be instantly dangling. It's a dangerous tool. That's why I would name it to convey the danger and leave no room for accidentally misusing it and suffering undefined behaviour as a result. (My choices on copying, moving, and ref qualifying are to get the compiler to detect likely misuse when it can.)

Comment: @chris Ah, yes. This makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A helper class:

```
struct int_ptr {
    int v;

    operator int *() { return &v; }
};

int foo(int *a, int b);

void bar()
{
    foo(int_ptr{0}, 0);
}
```

This results in a construction of a temporary `int_ptr` class, initializing its `v` member to 0. This gets passed as a parameter to a function that takes an `int *`, and `int_ptr` provides a suitable `operator *` method that passes the right pointer to the function.

This entire house of cards hinges on the fact that the `int_ptr` temporary exists until the end of the function call. You should pick a name for the helper class to underline that fact. If you always use it to pass a pointer to 0 to foo, then spell it out:

```
struct zero_value_to_foo {
    int v=0;

    operator int *() { return &v; }
};

int foo(int *a, int b);

void bar()
{

    foo(zero_value_to_foo{}, 0);
}
```

So that using it in other contexts will look to be very much out of place, i.e.

```
int *p=zero_value_to_foo{};
```

This compiles, but leaves you with a dangling pointer; but hopefully the "zero_value_to_foo" label gives a honking clue that something is wrong here.

Another little thing you can do to help yourself from misusing this is to [use a ref qualifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#const-.2C_volatile-.2C_and_ref-qualified_member_functions) for the operator:

```
struct zero_value_to_foo {
    int v=0;

    operator int *() && { return &v; }
};
```

With this,

```
foo(zero_value_to_foo{}, 0);
```

still compiles, but not this:

```
zero_value_to_foo zero{};

foo(zero, 0);
```

The more that can be done to make it difficult to use this except in the context is meant for, the fewer opportunities there are for bugs to creep by.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to pass a pointer to an integer 0, and not the 0 (NULL) pointer.

If you don't mind allocating dynamic memory you can do this:

```
func(new uint32_t(0), b);
```

However, then you'd have to make sure to deallocate the memory inside the function.

Alternatively, you can use an R-value references (c++11).
Then you can use the address of the reference as the pointer inside your function.

R-value reference syntax:

```
uint32_t func(uint32_t &&a, uint32_t b);
```

Comment: The function cannot be modified. i.e. it belongs to a library. But I don't mind allocating it dynamic memory and it works for me. Thank you!

Comment: I am glad to help. However, note that heap allocation (`new uint32_t(0)`) takes much longer than stack allocation (`uint32_t a = 0;`)

Comment: Right. I had not taken this into account. And since I am trying to optimize the program and would be using this function call multiple times this might be troublesome. I'll look into some benchmarks and see the affect on my code.

Comment: @pleasehalp, If you can't modify the function, then there's no way you're freeing this memory, which is a problem.

Comment: `func(new uint32_t(0), b);` is a memory leak if `func` doesn't delete the pointer.

Comment: @chris unless he's globally overridden `new` but that seems unlikely...